# How to plot the frequency histogram of a given data?

Tags: distributions, histograms

```
mydata = {
    45,171,197,31,136,195,60,38,19,158,75,198,100,65,188,53,9,150,148,33,25,133,158,152,146,63,25,64,125,67,186,166,62,55,92,49,155,175,171,141,9,112,25,58,138,168,189,84,193,95,83,192,190,104,50,148,184,197,163,163,144,154,69,86,47,99,148,120,71,106,102,115,45,35,103,190,43,88,183,186,190,193,129,40,165,179,27,28,106,33,85,54,172,88,179,34,200,173,30,54,156,129,14,68,39,49,128,159,149,76,111,193,186,174,185,81,53,43,152,25,22,89,27,29,143,52,198,62,66,80,33,77,119,55,102,140,19,32,198,118,109,62,131,21,113,113,168,15,87,104,41,15,103,23,72,179,142,28,40,145,153,156,42,170,44,34,53,167,104,28,44,96,184,195,35,129,131,183,66,74,19,13,10,163,147,92,43,103,165,80,73,170,166,85,102,80,142,190,41,184,140,32,59,105,104,184,148,199,171,45,185,77,101,176,81,85,171,81,45,134,95,79,48,40,39,102,17,36,34,63,32,16,157,33,23,159,141,23,15,69,12,104,155,50,45,159,189,38,96,153,9,93
};
```

Given the above data, how to plot its frequency distribution histogram? The required group spacing and number of groups can be adjusted

Comment: Please post your data as a list so that it can be copied and pasted into Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) provides functionality. See documentation to customize binning, and options such as *hspec*,e.g.
[image]

```
s = "45 171 197 31 136 195 60 38 19 158 75 198 100 65 188 53 9 150 \
148 33 25 133 158 152 146 63 25 64 125 67 186 166 62 55 92 49 155 175 \
171 141 9 112 25 58 138 168 189 84 193 95 83 192 190 104 50 148 184 \
197 163 163 144 154 69 86 47 99 148 120 71 106 102 115 45 35 103 190 \
43 88 183 186 190 193 129 40 165 179 27 28 106 33 85 54 172 88 179 34 \
200 173 30 54 156 129 14 68 39 49 128 159 149 76 111 193 186 174 185 \
81 53 43 152 25 22 89 27 29 143 52 198 62 66 80 33 77 119 55 102 140 \
19 32 198 118 109 62 131 21 113 113 168 15 87 104 41 15 103 23 72 179 \
142 28 40 145 153 156 42 170 44 34 53 167 104 28 44 96 184 195 35 129 \
131 183 66 74 19 13 10 163 147 92 43 103 165 80 73 170 166 85 102 80 \
142 190 41 184 140 32 59 105 104 184 148 199 171 45 185 77 101 176 81 \
85 171 81 45 134 95 79 48 40 39 102 17 36 34 63 32 16 157 33 23 159 \
141 23 15 69 12 104 155 50 45 159 189 38 96 153 9 93";
d = ImportString[s, "Table"][[1]];
Histogram[d]
```

[image]

Comment: The ordinate requirement is frequency divided by group distance